# Simple Probability Question but I can't understand one step.

Tags: probability

Five horses are in a race. Audrey picks two of the horses at random, and bets on them. Find the probability $p$ that Audrey picked the winner.

Answer is $\frac{2}{5}$.

However, I can't seem to understand one of the steps to the solution which states:

$$\frac{\binom 21+\binom 21}{\binom 52}$$

I don't get why the numerator has two $\binom 21$.

My thought process is $\frac{P(\text{number of ways to choose 1 winner})}{P(\text{total number of ways to choose 2 out of 5 horses})}$.

So shouldn't the $P(\text{number of ways to choose 1 winner}) = \binom 21$ because we are choosing one winner out of the two horses Audrey picked out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whoever wrote that answer should have provided some words to explain where it comes from.  The number is right, but I don't find an obvious thought that justifies it.  Sometimes from the expression you can see the logic behind it.  I could claim it is $\frac 25$ because we have assumed each horse has an equal chance to win.  I could claim it is $\frac {2 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}=\frac 25$ because there are $2 \choose 1$ ways to choose the winner from Audrey's picks and $5 \choose 1$ ways to choose the winner from the field.  Those are examples of the type of explanation I would expect.  What justification was given?